# Running modules on Python (Scrapy in this case)

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I tried to install scrapy using pip, and miniconda and it would say it was installed but would give me an error when trying to import the module on my IDLE (Python 3.7). Later I got it to work when running my IDLE through CMD but I would rather just be able to open my IDLE and use it straight on there. It is most likely an issue with file locations or paths but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I noticed the only way scrapy worked is when i used the miniconda 3.6.5 python. When I type in pip on cmd it does not exist but in my python 3.7 when I search for the module pip it returns a result as version 10.0.1. So since cmd does not recognize pip i cannot install scrapy on python 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you have multiple versions of python are installed with different paths in your computer. You try

```
import sys
sys.version
sys.path
```

on both CMD and IDLE and see they are matching.(They probably aren't) And you can choose which version you like to keep and remove the other. Or you can remove both versions and perform a clean installation and all the modules using pip.

Comment: They were not the same version but I already uninstalled both ands reinstalled python 3.7 but it still does not recognize pip on cmd.

Comment: Did you add python to the path in environment variables?

Comment: Yes, when I clean installed I chose the custom option to add it to environment variables.

Comment: what happens when you run pip install scrapy on cmd?

Comment: Command "c:\users\steam\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\steam\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pnqviehs\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\steam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-uw_grxod\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\steam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pnqviehs\lxml\             IN RED

Comment: ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: are you using python 32 bit version or 64?

Comment: you can install precompiled binaries of scrapy to work around installing visual studio. Find scrapy from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and install it using pip install like this.
pip install "path to the whl file"